# Which version of liferay IDE is compatible with Liferay 6.2, jdk 1.6.0

Tags: liferay-ide, liferay-6.2

My problem is as the subject tells , moreover I am not able to find any documentation about this .. Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I found that [2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/2.0.0%20GA1/) is convenient